# Angularjs pass variable to filter in controller

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

ReferenceError: data is not defined

Angularjs pass variable to filter in controller

Hi all

I'm still new to Angularjs so could have this completely wrong.

I'm trying to display a twitter feed and use a filter which will use a factory to parse the links in the twitter feed.

I get an error ReferenceError: data is not defined

Do I need to pass the data from the 'TwitterCtrl' to the 'parseTwitterLinks'

How can I do this?

The html looks like this

```
<p><span id="retweet-icon"></span><span ng-bind-html-unsafe="tweet.text | parseTwitterLinks"></span></p>
```

The TwitterCtrl

```
myApp.controller('TwitterCtrl', ['$scope','$http','twitter','$rootScope','$filter','parseTwitterLinksFilter', function($scope, $http, twitter, $rootScope, $filter, parseTwitterLinksFilter){

    $scope.tabId = false;
    $scope.tweet = false;


    $scope.$on('tabId', function(event, tabId) {

        if(tabId != $scope.tabId) {
            $scope.tabId = tabId;
            if($scope.tabId) {
                $scope.fetchTweet();
            } else {
                $scope.tweet = {};
            }
        }
    });

    $scope.fetchTweet = function() {

        var dataUrl = '/twitter?tab=' + $scope.tabId;

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: dataUrl
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){

        if(data) {
            $scope.tweet = data;
        } else {
            $scope.tweet = {};
        }      

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.tweet = {};
        });
    };

}])
```

The filter

```
myApp.filter('parseTwitterLinks', [function(){

  return function(text) {
    var tweet = data; 
    if(typeof tweet.text != 'undefined') {
        tweet.text = twitter.parseLinks(tweet.text);
    }
    $scope.tweet = tweet;
  }

  return tweet.text;

}]);
```

The factory to parse the links

```
myApp.factory('twitter', function($rootScope) {

    return {

        parseLinks: function(str) {
            var that = this;
            str = str || '';
            str = that.parseUrl(str);
            str = that.parseUsername(str);
            str = that.parseHashtag(str);
            return str
        },
        parseUrl: function(str) {
            str = str || '';
            return str.replace(/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=~]+/g, function(url) {
                return '<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank">'+url+'</a>';
            });
        },
        parseUsername: function(str) {
            str = str || '';
            return str.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(username) {
                return '<a href="http://twitter.com/'+username.replace("@","")+'" target="_blank">'+username+'</a>';
            });
        },
        parseHashtag: function(str) {
            str = str || '';
            return str.replace(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(tag) {
                return '<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q='+tag.replace("#","%23")+'" target="_blank">'+tag+'</a>';
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter 'parseTwitterLinks' is using "**data**", shouldn't you use "**text**"?

```
myApp.filter('parseTwitterLinks', [function(){

  return function(text) {
    var tweet = text; // <-- text instead of data ?
    if(typeof tweet.text != 'undefined') {
        tweet.text = twitter.parseLinks(tweet.text);
    }
    $scope.tweet = tweet;
  }

  return tweet.text;

}]);
```